# Error testing windows_package resource in chefspec

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have chef resource as follows

```
windows_package node['besclient']['exe_display_name'] do
  installer_type :installshield
  source "#{download_dir}\\BESClient-installer.exe"
end
```

where in attributes file I have `default['besclient']['exe_display_name'] = 'IBM BigFix Client'` and `download_dir = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}\\BESClient"`

For testing this I have the following test

```
it 'installs a windows_package with attributes' do
     expect(chef_run).to install_windows_package('IBM BigFix Client').with(
     installer_type: :installshield,
     source: "#{download_dir}\\BESClient-installer.exe"
)
end
```

where `download_dir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BigFix Enterprise\\BESClient"`
But this keeps giving the following error:

```
besclient::windows
  Windows 2012R2: when all attributes are default
    converges successfully
    installs a windows_package with attributes (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) besclient::windows Windows 2012R2: when all attributes are default installs
 a windows_package with attributes
     Failure/Error:
       expect(chef_run).to install_windows_package('IBM BigFix Client').with(
         installer_type: :installshield,
         source: "#{download_dir}\\BESClient-installer.exe"
       )

       expected "windows_package[IBM BigFix Client]" to have parameters:

         source "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BigFix Enterprise\\BESClient\\BESClien
t-installer.exe", was "c:\\program files (x86)\\bigfix enterprise\\besclient\\be
sclient-installer.exe"
     # ./spec/unit/recipes/windows_spec.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in <top (requ
ired)>'

Finished in 4.74 seconds (files took 17.56 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/unit/recipes/windows_spec.rb:47 # besclient::windows Windows 2012R2
: when all attributes are default installs a windows_package with attributes
```

I have defined the runner as follows

```
runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2012R2',file_cache_path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\BigFix Enterprise')
runner.converge(described_recipe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` property gets run through some coercion logic including [`downcase!`](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/f8a74d90c4c399e9ed90c5beaed6e4e72b36a570/chef-config/lib/chef-config/path_helper.rb#L118-L125). You'll have to adjust your test to match.